# What is the equivalent for Bicycle[]::new

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

In the code bellow there is a statement like this: .toArray(Bicycle[]::new). What would be the Lambda equivalent to this statment?

I checked that toArray receives a implementation of IntFunction. If I undertood right IntFunction is an Interface Functional that has a apply method that could receive an int and return a Bicycle[]. I don't know what is this int that it receives to try to mount the Lambda equivalent.

```
package br.com.testes;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TesteMethodReference {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> bikeBrands = Arrays.asList("Giant", "Scott", "Trek", "GT");

        Bicycle[] bicycles = bikeBrands.stream()
          .map(Bicycle::new) //the same .map((brand) -> new Bicycle(brand))
          .toArray(Bicycle[]::new); //WHAT IS THE LAMBDA EQUIVALENT?

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(bicycles));

    }

}

class Bicycle {

    private String brand;

    public Bicycle(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bicycle [brand=" + brand + "]";
    }
}
```

May anyone help me to understand it?

Thank you

Comment: `(size) -> new Bicycle[size]` - it's an array constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API note from the documentation of [`<A> A[] toArray​(IntFunction<A[]> generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction))

> The generator function *takes an integer*, which is the size
>   of the desired array, and *produces an array of the desired size*.

which is equivalent to what Bergi pointed out in the comments as well:

```
.toArray(size -> new Bicycle[size])
```